# ImportError: cannot import name '_log_class_usage' from 'torchtext.utils'

Tags: python, pytorch, torchtext

I recently updated pytorch and torchtext from anaconda, in order to run [this tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/torchtext_translation_tutorial.html) from the torchtext website, but it seems that my installation of torchtext has been broken. Everytime that I try `import torchtext` I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_log_class_usage' from 'torchtext.utils' (c:\Users\ferdi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torchtext\utils.py)
```

Uninstalling torchtext then reinstalling with `conda install -c pytorch torchtext` does not help.
Does anybody have an idea for how to solve it? My torch version is 1.13.0.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed there is always a specific torchtext version for the torch version and it is essential that they are aligned. According to https://pypi.org/project/torchtext/ the torchtext version you need is 0.14.0, and the latest version is 0.15.0. So if you simply do `conda install -c pytorch torchtext` you'd download the wrong version.